# Bulk Insert trazendo informações sem acentuação

Tags: sql, sql-server

Caros,

Boa Tarde!

Estou com um problema quando realizo um bulk insert do excel para o SQLServer, tenho um coluna chamada cidade e quando faço o bulk insert e incluo as informações no banco elas perdem as configurações, exemplo SÃO PAULO vira S+O PAULO, alguém pode me ajudar com isso?
Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Você teria algum código para compartilhar conosco?

Comment: de uma olhada nesse material https://support.microsoft.com/pt-br/help/3136780/utf-8-encoding-support-for-the-bcp-utility-and-bulk-insert-transact-sq

Comment: Há alguns anos passei por isso, acho que na ocasião eu tinha resolvido convertendo o arquivo excel para utf-8 ou para utf-16 e fazendo o bulk em uma tabela tipando as colunas de texto para nvarchar.

Comment: Esse comportamento é típico de conjunto de caracteres diferentes entre a fonte de dados e a coluna (ou do banco de dados ou da instância). Para quem estiver com o mesmo problema, configure a opção `CODEPAGE` no BULK INSERT.